# why user space kernel space sepearation in linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am trying to understand what makes the linux to go for sepration of user space and kernel space ?

I have some below basic understanding but I want to know more details.

1. If user allows the access to hardware it is more prone to errors
2. portability reasons.

Comment: How about: If you log in as you at the same time I log in as me, I don't want you to mess with my stuff unless I let you?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot one of the most important reasons: so that security controls (e.g., root vs non-root access, file permissions, application memory space isolation, etc.) can be enforced.

If user code had the same access as kernel code, user code could bypass all the security-related bookkeeping data in the kernel. e.g., a normal user could then overwrite the current uid field to 0, automatically making them root.